# Ensure only classes that implement a certain interface can call a method? C#?

Tags: c#

Ok, this may be a newbie question. So apologies.
Lets say I have a class with a method like:

```
public class A 
{
    public void DoSomething(long x)
    {
    }
}
```

Now I want to ensure that any object or class that calls DoSomething() MUST implement a certain interface like ISomethingInterface?

Is it possible to do that in C#?
Thanks

Comment: Care to explain why?

Comment: Why not invert it and make the method a part of the interface contract.  The method could take a parameter of type A.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It will be better if you can tell what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @DarrenYoung I would add this doesn't enforce the implementation of DoSomething(), only that one exists

Comment: This is what I love about programming. So many ways to crack an egg =P

Comment: What you're describing is an interface, with the exception that your function should be part of the interface definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is kind of strange because you are trying to implement something similar to an interface scenario but kind of upside down.

If you really want only classes implementing a certain interface to be able to call some particular method I would enforce it with extension methods:

```
 public static void DoSomething(this IFoo foo, long x)
 {
     ....
 }
```

Now you can only call `DoSomething(long x)` through an `IFoo` typed object. See [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb383977.aspx) for more info.

Of course an equivalent solution but not so convenient or elegant is to simply implement a static method like so:

```
 public static void DoSomething(IFoo foo, long x) { ... }
```

You are switching calling `DoSomething` from only `IFoo` objects to passing an `IFoo` object as an argument. Extension methods are essentially a syntactic sugar of this solution.

But this scenario really doesn't make sense unless you don't have access to `IFoo`'s implementation (third party code) or changing the interface is a breaking change you can't afford. If you do have access or can afford the break, then just make `DoSomething` part of the interface. That way all `IFoo` objects will have a `DoSomething` method.

Not sure if I've understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A : IA
{
       public void DoSomething(long x)
        {
           }
}

public interface IA
{
     void DoSomething(long x)
}


/*Some method somewhere*/
public void DoThisThing()
{
   IA a = new A();

   a.DoSomething(10);
}
```

You are sort of on the right lines, but it works the other way round. The interface tells you what you can do, it acts like a contract.

Now you can enforce your contract on other classes making sure you can only call `DoSomething`

```
public class B : IA
{
    public void DoSomething(long x)
    {
        // B's custom implementation
    }

    public void IWantSomethingElse(string s)
    { 
        // this is only class specific and cannot be called from the interface
    }
}

/* Some method somewhere */
public void DoThisThing()
{
    IA a = new B();

    a.DoSomething(2);

    // here there is no way to call IWantSomethingElse because the its not on the interface
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to enforce the scenario where a user must implement interface B if they also have A, then you can simply mark a interface to re-implement another. See [MSDN - Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664594(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
public interface A
{
   void a();
}

public interface B : A
{
   void b();
}

public class Foo: B
{
    public void a()
    {
    }


    public void b()
    {
    }
}
```

If they don't implement both methods then this will throw a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an abstract class that implements your function instead of an interface:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    //This one HAS to be defined in the inheritor class, like an interface
    public abstract void DoSomeOtherThing();

    //This is your function that can only be called by objects that inherit from this class.
    protected void DoSomething()
    {
        //use your protected method here 
    }
}

public class MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    public override void DoSomeOtherThing()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I like this method, and I think in this scenario it pertains more closely to what the OP asked for. Personally I would go with this.